# Setting my base_url to Secure

Tags: magento-1.9, https, redirect-url, querystring

Setting my base_url to HTTPS drops the query string

I set the base URL for my site to `https://www.example.com`, now when user comes to my site from a non secure URL (link) that has a query at the end of it (`http://www.example.com/path/to/page?foo=555&bar=444`) it gets redirected to the https page (`https://www.example.com/path/to/page`), however the queries get removed :-( I need them to stay, so the final URL would be `https://www.example.com/path/to/page?foo=555&bar=444`

I found in the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` class there is a method (line 441) `_checkShouldBeSecure` that sets the redirect to secure

```
protected function _checkShouldBeSecure($request, $path = '')  {
   if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost()) {
       return;
   }

   if ($this->_shouldBeSecure($path) && !$request->isSecure()) {

       $url = $this->_getCurrentSecureUrl($request);

       if ($request->getRouteName() != 'adminhtml' && Mage::app()->getUseSessionInUrl()) {
           $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->getRedirectUrl($url);
       }

       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
           ->setRedirect($url)
           ->sendResponse();
       exit;
   }
}
```

i want to make a local override and add this line

```
       if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {$url .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];};
```

Is that safe? will it cause any problems? is there a better way for me to go about preserving the query string?

Comment: Can you give example of Full url you are passing in browser?

Comment: @ChiragRajput added

Comment: check my answer.  is it working correct for you ?

Comment: had you tried my answer? . if it not works then i can improve answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit your htaccess file for this kind of redirect. See below:

```
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: the problem i am having with this is i already have a diffrent rule which is restricting admin to certian IPs and the admin stops working because of too mant redirects when i put your rule in my rule is : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin[NC]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^112.234.55.234`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]`

Comment: your answer would work on other servers but my problem was i had pound sitting in front of my server (for varnish) :-) .i switched it to haproxy and that is redirecting all my traffic to HTTPS and so I dont need anything in the .htaccesss, thank you

Comment: Cool. happy to hear your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Please abandon your current direction for resolution, unless you are certain that something in the core has been modified in the past. The issue is more than likely that you have some settings that require updating.

Here are some things you need to check:

- Contents of **.htaccess** - Please post the content of your .htaccess, less anything that may contain sensitive information.
- System Admin configuration settings for all scopes:

  - web/unsecure/base_url
  - web/secure/base_url
  - web/secure/use_in_frontend
  - web/cookie/cookie_path
  - web/cookie/cookie_domain
- Redirects/rewrites in your url rewrite tables (core_url_rewrite, for example)
- Redirection settings that may have been applied in something like CPanel/WHM
- Httpd / Vhost settings

---

If I had to take a guess, I would say that there needs to be some updates to the admin settings, or you have some rewrite/redirect forcing HTTPS redirection before the request even gets to Magento's framework.