# How to remove index.php from url if we enter manually

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, redirect-url

How to remove index.php when we enter manually in the URL

My store path is /var/www/html/testfolder/

Thanks

Comment: Please try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222469/setting-my-base-url-to-secure/222477#222477

Comment: Hi @raghu help me if you have any idea about this tasK:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232633/mageto-custom-api-update-inventory

Comment: Hi @ raghu find the link for product add soap api :https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your .htaccess after RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php     
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change domain.com to your domain and check do you use http or https.
Its worked for me. When I enter address with index.php its redirecting to domain.

Comment: Updated , becuase was issue with different pages, now is fine.

Comment: yes working thankyou

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure that Apache rewrites module is enabled on your server and then follow the below steps...

1. **Login** to Magento admin account and go to this path - **System > Configuration > General > Web**.
2. Select the **yes** for **Use Web Server Rewrites** in **Search Engine Optimization** (on **Web** settings).
3. Now, Go to Magento root directory and add following code in **.htaccess**.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

`</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

It require enable **mod_rewrite** module

Use web server rewrite **"Yes"** from admin setting

Check refrence from here : [How to remove index.php from your Magento site URL](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-remove-index-php-from-your-magento-site-url.html)

Comment: thanks...it is there but when we enter manually index.php it should not show

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

remove `index.php` change in below path 
Override file in local and `_updatePathUseRewrites` comment line 599 and 606

```
app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php
```

Comment: tried this now but same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it through .htaccess file of your magento root directory. Add the following code to your .htaccess it should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.your-domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks this is not working and I have the path for magento /var/www/html/testfolder/

Comment: Check the updated answer.