# Magento 1.9 custom api update inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I am updating the cataloginventory_stock_item custom quanty values based on stock ids by using custom api.

I written a update table query in custom api module model file:

Like below:

```
 public function hello() {

$new_quantity='586';
$id='5949';
$stock_id='3';
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql = "UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET qty = '{$new_quantity}' WHERE stock_id = '{$stock_id}' and product_id = $id";
$update=$conn->query($sql);
return true;
  }
}
```

But here in this file iam passing the values in this file only, but I want to pass the values from api file which is running from root folder.

How to pass the values from api file which is in root folder.

Root folder api file:

```
<?php

$soap = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/soap/?wsdl=1', array('exceptions' => 0));
$sessionId = $soap->login('test','test@123');

$result = $soap->call($sessionId, 'customapi.hello',array($myhellomsg));

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html

Comment: try this : http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/update-product-stock-directly-from-magento-database/

Comment: thanks for your answer i wants to update values using api file , how can pass values to that function from my api file is in root folder